# iOS - ObjectiveC: Reload UITableView with pull to Search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reload, searchbar

I have a `UITableView` with a custom `search bar` on top (of header). On `viewDidLoad` I hide the search bar by setting `mytableView.content.offset.y = mySearchBar.frame.size.height`. I also have a reload button witch reloads the whole view. My problem is that every time it reloads, tableView "bumps" when content.offset changes. I need to reload, not just update tableView cells. Any ideas how to reload my tableView with hidden search bar and manage that "bump" issue??Thanks!

view hierarchy

- tableView

  - search bar
  - header
  - cell

Comment: "I have a UITableView with a custom search bar on top of it." - Can you explain what this means? On top in the table header? above the whole tableview? over the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve something similar with placing both views over the UITableView.

```
RefreshView *view = [RefreshView refreshView];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height);
[self.tableView addSubview:view];
```

When loading start I do:

```
UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
inset.top = 110.0f; //height of my refresh view
scrollView.contentInset = inset;
```

And when it's done:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
inset.top = 0.0f;
scrollView.contentInset = inset;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This way the view is behaving nicely and following always contentOffset even if table is empty.